# How to put squares in shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting

I have written some code for triangles identification but not able to write for right angle triangle.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "enter the value of a"
read a
echo "enter the value of b"
read b
echo "enter the value of c"
read c
if [ $c = $a = $b ]
then
echo "Its a equilateral triangle"
fi
if [ $c != $a != $b ]
then
echo "Its a Triangle"
fi
```

Comment: @anubhava Right-triangle can be determined using Pythagoras which is A^2 + B^2 = C^2. That's where the squares come in

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ ($a*$a) + ($b*$b) = ($c*$c) ]
then
echo "right angle in triangle"
fi
```

Comment: its not working in sh scripting. Metacharacter * is not readable

Answer (score 0):

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the value of a"
read a
echo "enter the value of b"
read b
echo "enter the value of c"
read c

if ((c == a && c == b )); then
    echo "Its a equilateral triangle"
    exit 0
fi

if ((c != a || c != b )); then
    echo "Its a Triangle"
fi
```

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr